Estimate circle crossing time between two coordinates points in wgs84
I am trying to estimate the crossing time of a circle given two point P1, P2 one inside and the other one outside of the buoy.

So given the following (Coords in WGS):
lat1, lon1, t1 = 45.965467, 8.509283, datetime(2024, 6, 19, 11, 46, 39) # P1 
lat2, lon2, t2 = 45.968483, 8.5089, datetime(2024, 6, 19, 11, 57, 12) # P2 
lat_c, lon_c, r = 45.987168002, 8.452897189, 4500  # Bouy center coordinates and radius

I need to find an estimated crossing time. Typically, if it all works, I have a sample per second and take the last outside to define the crossing time, but sometimes GPS get lost, especially in mountain hiking races and I need to interpolate.
What is the best approach with Python? I believe it must include (haversine distance calculations, bearings since it can be crossed sideways, speeds etc etc)?

theoretically (using math) you have line between to points and you can get points on this line and split it in many points (and split time between beginning and end point) and claculate distance bouy (lat_c - a)^2 + (lon_c-y)^2 - and if two nearest points are: one > r^2 and other < r^2 then it cross circle.

similar idea: you have two points - use them to calculate middle point (and middle time) and if middle point is on the same side (of circle) as first point then use middle point instead of first point, if middle point is on the same side (of circle) as second point then use middle point instead of second point - and repeat all again. After few steps you should have some approximation.
